# A good solution to switch between different network settings?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking

I use my laptop (Windows Vista Ultimate) to connect to a wireless network in college, which assigns a dynamic IP address, and at home, with a static IP address and DNS server.
I'm looking for a good solution/software to switch between college/home settings without changing them manually.
I've found an open-source application called [Network Switcher](http://wiki.ricardoamaral.net/en/network-switcher), but the official site says that its development has been discontinued.

Any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Funny because I know the guy who coded Network Switcher. What functionality are you looking for? He could have stopped development because he feels nothing is really missing. Apps are the best when they are simple. Anyway you can reach him on neowin he's there a lot: http://www.neowin.net/forum/index.php?showuser=22268

Comment: Here's another one that is under active development: http://sourceforge.net/projects/argonswitcher/

Comment: My favourite solution is to actually configure the home router to provide a fixed IP address to your laptop (usually identified by MAC address). Therefore you need zero configuration on the laptop and can just leave it configured as dynamic IP for all environments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are two programs to switch between pre-configured network settings:

**[IP Organizer 2](http://www.bilgisayar-dunyasi.com/yazilim/iporganizer.html)**

[image: Screenshot]

The website is in Turkish. Here's the [download link](http://www.bilgisayar-dunyasi.com/yazilim/dosyalar/IP_Organizer2.exe).

*IP Organizer is freeware.*

**[NetSetMan](http://www.netsetman.com/index.php?s=nsm)**

[image: Screenshot]

*NetSetMan is free for personal use.*

Comment: you're more than welcome.

Answer (score 3):

If your solely problem is switching between DHCP-enabled and static IP networks on Windows, then you don't need any extra software at all. Since ye olde Windows XP days you can switch between "normal" and "alternate" configs for your network connections. Go to your Network and Sharing Center, find your connection (it may be the active one), click on it (or double click if you had to go to Change Adapter Settings), click on Properties, Internet Protocol Version 4 or 6 (TCP/IPv4 or v6).

Then in the dialog you'll see the usual network configuration and a tab for an "Alternative Configuration". You can set up one for your automatic configuration via DHCP and another one for a static IP configuration. When there's no DHCP server, Windows will use the other one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but I've found [this](http://www.lockergnome.com/windows/2008/01/15/change-your-network-location-in-vista/).

It's for Vista, I don't know which OS you are using since you didn't mentioned it. I'd assume Windows 7 to have a similar feature.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not what I'm looking for, that doesn't create distinct settings for every network.

Comment: That has nothing to do with what the user asked... It only affects the security settings of the connection, not the connection itself.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the same advice, I found this article:

http://www.techmixer.com/free-network-ip-profile-managers-list/

The article lists NetSetMan and IP Organizer along a few others, namely: Net Profiles, Free IP Switcer and Cye Network Profile.

Answer (score 0):

Check the software that came with the laptop.  Dell's ship (or at least used to ship) with a program called QuickSet.  It caused a lot of problems for people because it would tend to disable your NIC if you were on battery power, and the cable was unplugged, but it did not detect when the status changed.   However if you disabled that, one of the cool features was the ability to set network profiles.  I used it to change the network settings, and even the default printer depending on which office I was in.

Answer (score 0):

[Mobile Net Switch](https://www.mobilenetswitch.com) is a good way to get started; you want to figure out what features you really need. Certain tools offer so many features, it becomes confusing. This tool is a good starting point (freeware, minor splash screen).

[image: Mobile Net Switch]