# Windows 8.1 manual DNS on a per wifi network basis?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, dns

How to configure Windows 8.1 with a specific manual DNS that is only valid for the current WiFi network?  The setting seems to associate with the WiFi card, not the network, resulting in a laptop that moves from site to site having the wrong manual DNS on every network except the original.  It appears the same would be true for manually assigning an IP address. I am accessing this from Control Panel:Network and Internet:Network and Sharing Center:(link next to my connection name):Properties:Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)/Properties and here I see the manual DNS entry which is erroneously being preserved from the previously connected network.

I also tried Control Panel:Network and Internet:Network and Sharing Center:Set up a new connection or network:Manually connect to a wireless network, but after I entered the password info it didn't provide any options to configuring the TCP/IP settings but instead just said the connection was created. (Although, strange enough, it doesn't show up from the Control Panel:Network and Internet:Connect to a network link which just brings up a side panel containing discovered WiFi networks!)

Comment: The default Windows networking settings don't allow you to have different configurations per network.  You'll need third party software for that.  See this [previous question](http://superuser.com/questions/47429/a-good-solution-to-switch-between-different-network-settings)

Comment: @ernie inconceivable!

Comment: @ernie I would vote to close, but there is no "This question can't be answered to the satisfaction of the asker, because the software is stupid and can't do a simple thing."

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you have access to the router of the network it would probably be better to "push" out the information you want that machine to have by using ip reservations.  But if you don't or that doesn't meet your needs, the only thing I can think of would be to write a powershell script that you write for that machine.  It would run based on network connection changed event kicked off by scheduled tasks and it would have to set the IP/DNS to the static info you want only if connecting to the network of interest, otherwise it would set to "dynamically configure"...  I'm 95% sure this could be done but would be a lot of work... It seems like there is a better option though...

Answer (score -1):

In network configs  for that and any other network in question  go to advanced and select DHCP --addressing only   and input the needed / desired DNS servers (aka name servers)  and relaunch that network to confirm the newly configured dns is in play this should be  persistent across boots as well for the networks in question

Comment: can you tell me the path to get to this "advanced" button/tab/link?

Comment: i'm currently trying Control Panel:Network and Internet:Network and Sharing Center:(link next to my connection name):Properties:Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)/Properties to get to the manual DNS entry which is erroneously being preserved from the previously connected network.

Comment: Try disconnecting then  and change it