# Multiple wifi configuration

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically picking network settings based on the wifi network.](https://superuser.com/questions/26368/automatically-picking-network-settings-based-on-the-wifi-network)

I'm using my laptop at the university, at work and back at home.
During the day I have the following problem: In the university there is no DHCP available and I have to setup my IP and my DNS while at home and at work there is one and I have to use automatic settings.

Is somehow possible to configure windows to automatically use preset settings depending on the name of the network?

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/26368/automatically-picking-network-settings-based-on-the-wifi-network or http://superuser.com/questions/47429/a-good-solution-to-switch-between-different-network-settings

Comment: If you are using a Lenovo/IBM ThinkPad, you can use their program, ThinkVantage Access Connections, to manage your different networks.