# Unique IP address settings (static/dhcp) per wireless network?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, dhcp, static-ip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically picking network settings based on the wifi network](https://superuser.com/questions/26368/automatically-picking-network-settings-based-on-the-wifi-network)

Is this possible in Windows 7? For example, I want to use `Static IP A` with `Network A`, `DHCP` with `Network B`, `Static IP B` with `Network C`, etc.

I know that under `TCP/IPv4` settings, there is an option for an alternate setup, but that only gives me two possible choices. I want more than two unique setups.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically picking network settings based on the wifi network](http://superuser.com/questions/26368/automatically-picking-network-settings-based-on-the-wifi-network) another dupe with better(?) answers: [A good solution to switch between different network settings?](http://superuser.com/questions/47429/a-good-solution-to-switch-between-different-network-settings)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[NetSetMan](http://www.netsetman.com/index.php?s=nsm) may be your *magic wand:*
[image]

Comment: how is it a magic wand? does it turn pumpkins into carriages? ;)

Comment: no, just change netsettings in one pass

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more about this program?

Comment: @Journeyman Geek:  I wonder if there's a "glass slippers" add-on that supports IPv6?

Comment: This looks to the most robust, free software package for managing multiple network profiles. I will give it a try.

Comment: @simon-sheehan - I hope, one screenshot from homepage can tells more than my 100 words, but I'll try: you write 6 networks settings profiles, link them to interface(s), can select any at any time - and profile settings will be applied to NIC(s), replacing old confiruration

Comment: @Lazy Badger:  I edited your answer to include the screen shot you mentioned.

Comment: Does not work for me despitefully.. My laptop has has a swicth that I have to turn off and back on and click the wifi icon that is pearing to enable wifi again.. after that the settings are not applied