# Save alternate DNS information

Tags: windows-7, dns

I can change my DNS settings for the connection that I am using via these windows, [image] but when I enter an alternate DNS, it gets clear every time I select the obtain DNS server address automatically.

Is there a way to save this information, or must I remember/copy down all the the DNS servers I use at one point or another?

Ideally I would like a drop down selection that would contain all of the addresses that I have used in the past, but probably the best I can hope for is just keeping the previous value.

Comment: **Related:** http://superuser.com/questions/356495/unique-ip-address-settings-static-dhcp-per-wireless-network

Comment: Just install and run your own [resolving proxy DNS server](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dns-server-roles.html#Proxy) on every individual machine, or on one machine servicing your whole LAN.  You'll never have to worry about this tedious nonsense of switching among _other people_'s DNS servers again.  You have a machine that is more than capable of running daemons that provide UDP/IP and TCP/IP services.  It's very likely already running several.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own scripts.

[netsh](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725935.aspx) should be pre-installed.

```
netsh interface ip set dnsserver "Wireless Network Connection" source=static addr=8.8.4.4
netsh interface ip set dnsserver "Wireless Network Connection" source=dhcp
```

If PowerShell is available,

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |
    Where { $_.Name -eq "Wireless Network Connection" } |
    Foreach-Object {
        $_.SetDNSServerSearchOrder(("8.8.4.4", "8.8.8.8"))
    }
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |
    Where { $_.Name -eq "Wireless Network Connection" } |
    Foreach-Object {
        $_.SetDNSServerSearchOrder()
    }
```

(I don't have Windows installed so I'm not 100% sure that's correct, but it should be close.)

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there is nothing like that built in, you have to rely on external software to add functionality to let you have "Network Profiles" so you can switch around. Its a very common scenario for laptop users, for example, to move around a lot and it would be really nice to have it built in. But, for now, applications it is.

Some recommendations:
NetSetMan at http://www.netsetman.com/
Net Profile Switch at http://www.jitbit.com/net-profile-switch/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unfortunately all the custom information is wiped when you click the automatic option (though it is not saved until you click *OK*, so you should be able to click *Cancel*).

What I usually do is to just back up the registry entry(ies) for my NIC(s) at `HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces` (each NIC gets its own GUID under this key, but it is pretty easy to identify them based on the `IPAddress` and `NameServer` values).

This way, I have a record of all of the network settings for my NIC in a nice, plain-text (ie, human-readable) format, and I can even restore it simply by merging the .REG file—and rebooting—(of course the GUID may change depending on the circumstances, but that is easy enough to fix).