# Manual settings for different wifi networks in windows 7

Tags: wireless-networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically picking network settings based on the wifi network](https://superuser.com/questions/26368/automatically-picking-network-settings-based-on-the-wifi-network)
>   [A good solution to switch between different network settings?](https://superuser.com/questions/47429/a-good-solution-to-switch-between-different-network-settings)

I have two wifi networks in my house. I want to maunally specify ip, gateway and dns for both of them in windows. If i open the wireless interface and edit IPv4 settings, won't those settings apply to all wifi connections? how do i set up individual settings for different wifi networks?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically picking network settings based on the wifi network](http://superuser.com/questions/26368/automatically-picking-network-settings-based-on-the-wifi-network) also see [A good solution to switch between different network settings?](http://superuser.com/questions/47429/a-good-solution-to-switch-between-different-network-settings)

Comment: If you leave Windows set as DHCP, your IP, DNS, and gateway settings should all come from the router itself.  Can you configure each router for a different DNS and assign your computer's MAC address a static IP?  That way you'll get the appropriate settings depending on which one you connect to.

Comment: i don't have dhcp server running on one of the routers, so i need to maunally set up the computer for that network.

@techie007 the second link seems the answer for me (NetSetMan). Thanks!!!